# Wordpress: Сделать обычную страницу архивной

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть произвольный тип записи Новости, который создан через плагин Toolset types. У этого типа записи есть архивная страница archive-news.php. Соответственно на архивной странице выводятся последние посты, но на ней имеются также такие разделы, как: Заголовок страницы, фоновое изображение в хедере и прочие поля, которые должны быть редактируемы через админку.

Но вот в чем проблема, я задаю в файле archive-news.php название шаблона news (Template Name: news) затем создаю страницу новостей в обычном списке страниц вордпрес, выбираю для ее отображения этот шаблон и все бы было хорошо, но вся проблема кроется в url, так как я не могу задать странице url к примеру site.com/news так как по этому url расположена архивная страница произвольного типа записей Новости.

Точнее url то поставить можно, НО при любых изменениях в настройке произвольного типа записи выбивает ошибку -
"Вы не можете использовать этот краткий заголовок, так как он уже используется или является зарезервированным словом. Выберите другой краткий заголовок."

То есть вордпрес видит созданную страницу Новости и архивную страницу Новостей как две разные страницы. Как можно указать, что страница является архивной и принадлежит определенному типу записей? На данный момент я вынужден ставить другой url для страницы новостей, при переходе на который выполняется редирект на архивную страницу, но это костыль какой-то,хотелось бы изначально указать что это не отдельная страница, а страница архива.

P.S. Если к примеру выводить все новости не на архивной странице, а на той странице новостей, что я создаю в списке обычных страниц вордпрес, а для произвольного типа записей Новости убрать has_archive, то все равно нельзя задать url как site.com/news потому-что news это название типа записи и оно не даст внести любые изменения в настройки этого типа записей, если будет создана страница, с аналогичным url.

Вообщем суть вопроса заключается в том, чтобы указать вордпресу, что страница является архивной и принадлежит определенному типу записей, чтобы можно было удобно через админку редактировать разделы этой страницы, такие как: заголовок, фоновое изображение и прочее.

Comment: А почему не поправить archive-news.php плагина?

Comment: Вы перекрыть своей страницей то, что решистрирует плагин, не сможете

Comment: @KAGG Design в каком смысле поправить archive-news.php? с ним вроде все ок, мне главное с url проблему решить, чтобы я мог задать странице Новости url site.com/news но это сделать не получается.

Comment: @KAGG Design то что не могу перекрыть это я заметил, вот как раз и ищу решение этой проблемы:)

Comment: site.com/news так как по этому url расположена архивная страница произвольного типа записей Новости.

Comment: @KAGG Design ну да, по этому адресу расположена архивная страница, а мне нужно чтобы эта архивная страница была редактируема через админку и была расположена в разделе обычных страниц. А в каком смысле поправить archive-news.php? я сам создал  archive-news.php, а не плагин и закинул туда код, в котором содержаться поля плагина advanced custom fields и они должны редактироваться в админке. Конечно можно эти поля вынести в страницу опций acf, но было бы удобней, если бы страница новостей была в списке всех страниц.

Answer (score 0):

Так в WordPress сделать нельзя. Не могут существовать одновременно страница `/news` и произвольный тип записей со слагом `/news`.

Вам надо править шаблон `archive-news.php`. Для его настройки из админки вводить туда произвольные поля с помощью плагина Advanced Custom Fields либо создать свои настройки темы в админке, что гораздо удобнее для восприятия. О кастомных настройках темы и плагинов можно почитать на русском [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html).

Answer (score 0):

Записи (POST) уже используются под другие нужды? Как правило именно их и оставляют под новости. Записям страницу архива можно назначить через настройки (Настройки -> Настройки чтения).

Если Post уже заняты, то тогда, при создании типа публикации через Toolset назовите его иначе (archive_news, например), а уже затем создавайте соответствующую страницу (со слагом NEWS). Ну а далее работайте с записями в файле page-news.php

Возможно будет проблема при удалении текущего типа публикации созданного через Toolset (NEWS будет по прежнему занят). Нужно читать документацию по Toolset и выяснять как полностью удалить упоминание типа публикации и освободить slug. Либо лезть в phpmyadmin и вычищать таблицу.